# How can I move a discussion from comments to chat after the 'move this discussion to chat' link has disappeared?

Tags: support, chat

So, I'm once again violating the policies of AU by having an extended discussion in comments.

The link offering to `move this discussion to chat` pops up. I get distracted and do not act on it immediately. When I bring my browser back to that question, the link is gone.

Now what? How can I accomplish the same thing that clicking on the `move this discussion to chat` link would have done?

---

Adding some links to questions on meta Stack Overflow that seem related or similar to this question as additional context.

[“move comments to chat” link disappeared](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/117587/147712)
[Should “move-to-chat” be provided on demand (as a button perhaps)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/100967/147712)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it isn't the same feature, what you can do is the following:

- Go to [chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/new](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/new) and make a new room.
- Then, leave a comment with the link of that new room.

If you can't create a room (for whatever reason), ping one of the moderators or just ask a high rep user [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room) to make one for you.

Comment: I actually do **not** like this answer. But that's because I do not like that this appears to be the **only** way of doing things at the moment than any fault in your answer per se. It would be nice if [se] would provide a "*button*" (or whatever) which  "moved a discussion in comments to chat". Oh, well. That suggestion appears to have already been asked and declined over on [metase]. :-(

Comment: @irrationalJohn yeah, i don't like it either, but it's appears to be (as you said) the only answer right now. :(